# Accessing pointer to pointer of struct using -> operator

Tags: c, pointers, struct, pointer-to-pointer

I have this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

void pointerOfPointer(struct node **reference)
{
    struct node *temporary = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    temporary->data = 100;
    temporary->next = 0;

    printf("before: temporary->data %d\n", temporary->data);
    temporary = *reference;
    printf("after: temporary->data %d\n", temporary->data);
}

int main()
{
    struct node *linkedlist = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    linkedlist->data = 15;
    linkedlist->next = 0;
    pointerOfPointer(&linkedlist);
    return 0;
}
```

How can I access the pointer to pointer of struct in the pointerOfPointer function without copying the *reference address to the temporary local variable? So in the end I can access the reference variable data using operator -> directly, like reference->data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that `foo->bar` is just syntactic sugar for `(*foo).bar`. What you're asking for is essentially `(**reference).data`, which you can rewrite as `(*reference)->data` if you want.